# What is the type of a map that is indexed by a union of strings and returns a number

Tags: typescript

I have a type that is a union of strings:

```
type OneMatcherType =
    | "one"
    | "two"
    | "three"
```

I want to have a map that is indexed by this type also returns a number:

```
let fOne = 3

let v: MapType = {
    "one": fOne,
    "two": fOne,
    "three": fOne
}
```

How do I declare this `MapType` so I can write this function:

```
function (key: OneMatcherType): number {
    return v[key]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

With a mapped object type and a bit of generics:

```
type OneMatcherType =
    | "one"
    | "two"
    | "three"

type MathcherMap = {
    [k in OneMatcherType]: number
}

const v: MathcherMap = {
    one: 3,
    two: 3,
    three: 3,
}

function returnMatch<K extends OneMatcherType>(key: K): MathcherMap[K] {
    return v[key];
}
```